# Silverlight - prevent TextBox height from growing with multiple lines

Tags: silverlight, textbox

I'm working on a control. This control is based on a `TextBox` with an additional option to edit multiline text in a popout.

The `TextBox` should not display multiple lines. I don't want to hardcode the height; how do I make sure the `TextBox` doesn't grow when it gets content containing multiple lines?

I can't strip them out and bind the textbox content to the modified version because of the way that SL handles textboxes internally.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the "multiline" property and "wordwrap" property to false.

Also you can set the maximum length property of the textbox.

I hope this will work.

Comment: A TextBox has neither a multiline nor a wordwrap property.

Comment: It does have a TextWrapping property and AcceptsReturn, but those don't impact this.

Comment: Actually I am a C# programmer.There I have used that, so I thought it would also work in SIlverlight :).